# Uploading images PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql, file-upload

I have problems with my upload script and hope somebody can help me with this.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Include the database configuration file
    include_once 'dbconfig.php';

    // File upload configuration
    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');


    $statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesSQL = $errorUpload = $errorUploadType = '';
    if(!empty(array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']))){
        foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key=>$val){
            // File upload path
            $fileName = basename($_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
            $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;

            // Check whether file type is valid
            $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
                // Upload file to server
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key], $targetFilePath)){
                    // Image db insert sql
                    $insertValuesSQL .= "('".$fileName."', NOW()),";

                }else{
                    $errorUpload .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].', ';

                }
            }else{
                $errorUploadType .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].', ';
            }
        }

        if(!empty($insertValuesSQL)){
            $insertValuesSQL = trim($insertValuesSQL,',');
            // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO images (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES $insertValuesSQL");
            if($insert){
                $errorUpload = !empty($errorUpload)?'Upload Error: '.$errorUpload:'';
                $errorUploadType = !empty($errorUploadType)?'File Type Error: '.$errorUploadType:'';
                $errorMsg = !empty($errorUpload)?'<br/>'.$errorUpload.'<br/>'.$errorUploadType:'<br/>'.$errorUploadType;
                $statusMsg = "Files are uploaded successfully.".$errorMsg;
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }

    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
    }

    // Display status message
    echo $statusMsg;

}
?>

<html>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select Image Files to Upload:
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>

    <input class="upload-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD">
</form>
</html>
```

If I click on the submit button and there are no images selected, the code print `Please select a file to upload.` on the screen.

If I click on the submit button with selected images the code shows nothing and does not upload any image.

Whats going wrong?

Comment: Include the <form> tag from your HTML as well

Comment: maybe missing the enctype attribute, so, providing your html code would help.

Comment: We would need to see your HTML including the `<form>`

Comment: Your form doesn't have an action? what is submitting the form going to do?

Comment: The action is on the same page.

Comment: Add error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors', 1); to the top of your file - then you should see more information on errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the FILES array is not correctly accessed. Try this code piece

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){
    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$val){
        // File upload path
        $fileName = basename($val['name']);
        $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;

        // Check whether file type is valid
        $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
            // Upload file to server
            if(move_uploaded_file($val["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
                // Image db insert sql
                $insertValuesSQL .= "('".$fileName."', NOW()),";

            }else{
                $errorUpload .= $val['name'].', ';

            }
        }else{
            $errorUploadType .= $val['name'].', ';
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my notes for your issues:

1) Make sure your upload folder is correct:

```
// File upload configuration
$targetDir = "uploads/";
```

In this case, the upload folder should be at **the same level** as your upload script.

```
|--uploads
|
|--your_upload_script.php
|
```

2) I removed your database script. It was working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="asset/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select Image Files to Upload:
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    <input class="upload-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Include the database configuration file
    //include_once 'dbconfig.php';

    // File upload configuration
    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');


    $statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesSQL = $errorUpload = $errorUploadType = '';
    if(!empty(array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']))){
        foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key=>$val){
            // File upload path
            $fileName = basename($_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
            $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;

            // Check whether file type is valid
            $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
                // Upload file to server
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key], $targetFilePath)){
                    // Image db insert sql
                    $insertValuesSQL .= "('".$fileName."', NOW()),";

                }else{
                    $errorUpload .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].', ';

                }
            }else{
                $errorUploadType .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].', ';
            }
        }

    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
    }

    // Display status message
    echo $statusMsg;

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

So, please check your database script again.
For better error tracking, **we should use `try catch` statement to catch exceptions**.

3) Uploading file errors:

```
$_FILES["files"]["error"][$key]
#Check some cases:
   case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
        break;
    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
        throw new RuntimeException('No file sent.');
    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
        throw new RuntimeException('Exceeded filesize limit.');
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
```

If you want to upload multi files, there are examples:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php
- [How to insert multiple images and move into folder in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869588/how-to-insert-multiple-images-and-move-into-folder-in-php/51869821#51869821)